# python help django navigation

Tags: python, django, navigation

I would like to understand how I can access and navigate Python and Django help.

1. in Django I cd to my directory and  entered the following command to access help of the manage.py:

python manage.py help

And I would like to get info on the commands. Here I have to type:

Type 'manage.py help ' for help on a specific subcommand.

But either combination did not work.

2. How do I get help in Python? Is there a way to list everything python has to offer? If not is there a online resource that gives an excellent overview?

Thanks

L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do

```
python manage.py --help
```

Here is the django admin.py/manage.py doc http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

To getting help in general in python you can use builtin  `help` function e.g.

```
>>> help('help')

Welcome to Python 2.5!  This is the online help utility.
....
```